# preventing php injection in forms (if a user submits php code into a form)

Tags: php, security, code-injection

In a contact form, if someone enters the following into the textbox:

```
<?php echo 'hi'; ?>
```

I see that the server will not execute it because of an error. What I would like it to do is instead, somehow escape it into plain text and display it correctly. I have seen other sites been able to do this. I originally thought this could be solved by the addslashes() function, but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: “I see that the server will not execute it because of an error.” Which error? You're not trying to `eval` user input, are you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) instead. Don't use [`addslashes`](http://php.net/addslashes).

To be more specific, `addslashes` bluntly escapes all instances of `'`, `"` and `\` and `NUL`. It was meant to prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), but it has no real use in proper security measures.

What you want is preventing the browser to interpret tags as is (and that's entirely different from preventing SQL injections). For instance, if I want to talk about `<script>` elements, SO shouldn't simply send that string literally, causing to start an actual script (that can lead to [Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)), but some characters, especially `<` and `>`, need to be *encoded* as HTML entities so they're *shown* as angle brackets (the same is true for `&`, that otherwise would be interpreted as the start of an HTML entity).

In your case, output after `htmlspecialchars` would look like:

```
&lt;?php echo 'hi'; ?&gt;
```

Comment: I am using htmlentities now? is that not good as well? if so, this doesn't seem to work

Comment: @user: No, it's deprecated and under normal circumstances not needed and only adds extra bandwidth. You can safely `echo` variables containing tags and code to an HTML page using `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: @Macel `htmlentities()` is deprecated?  I was not aware that this was the case; in fact, `htmlentities()` encodes a greater number of characters than `htmlspecialchars()` (see the note at the bottom of http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Comment: @Phoenix: yes, I know, but it is not needed. Just use correct encoding and you'll be fine. The only characters that *need* to be encoded are `<`, `>` and `&`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) before outputing anything provided by the user. But in this case, also make sure that you *do not* execute anything the user inputs. Do not use eval, include or require. If you save the user data to a file, use [readfile](http://php.net/readfile) or [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents)+htmlspecialchars instead of include/require. If you're using eval, change it into echo and so on.